# Android edittext : show swim out prompt with last logged in email

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, prompt, hint

I have email edittext field and need to show last successful logged in values of email, if first characters of them are equal.

I know, that successful logged in values I can store in the sharedPreferences. But how can I show it and when user clicks on it, it have to be setted in the login EditText.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html Use the AutoCompleteTextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an auto complete EditText as login field like in this page http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext